# Blogger : Facebook share button for each post using iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe, blogger

Can't get facebook share button (IFRAME) to show for each separate blog post on Blogger.

Im using the FB dev share button configurator
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button#configurator

I can get javascript to work, but I can't seem to place my button neatly.
Tried FB iframe and I can place button neatly.

with iframe :
I can't get the blog post to list.
It asks for a http url , rather than say data:post.url

Blogger uses XML.

Can anyone say what iframe code I would use for a FB share button on each blogger blog post ?

example for 'facebook.com' (which works)

Answer (score 2):

Put this code in your bolg post footer

```
<a class='facebook share' expr:href='&quot;http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=&quot; + data:blog.url' onclick='window.open(this.href, &apos;windowName&apos;, &apos;width=550, height=600, left=24, top=24, scrollbars, resizable&apos;); return false;' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>facebook</a>
```